# Simple htaccess redirect without query string

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, query-string

I want to redirect the following link 
`http://www.example.com/full-tang-polished-samurai-katana-sword.html` to `http://www.example.com/final-fantasy-advent-children-cloud-buster-sword.html`

I used several methods including

```
Redirect 301 /full-tang-polished-samurai-katana-sword.html http://www.example.com/final-fantasy-advent-children-cloud-buster-sword.html
```

Which produces

```
http://www.example.com/final-fantasy-advent-children-cloud-buster-sword.html?full-tang-polished-samurai-katana-sword.html
```

I can not handle this querystring

```
?full-tang-polished-samurai-katana-sword.html
```

Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have resolved this issue, the code is as below

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/full-tang-polished-samurai-katana-sword.html$  http://www.example.com/final-fantasy-advent-children-cloud-buster-sword.html
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^full-tang-polished-samurai-katana-sword.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/final-fantasy-advent-children-cloud-buster-sword.html? [R=301,L]
```